# node's get() function is never called when serving static files

Tags: node.js, express, routes, get, static

When I go to localhost:3000, app.get() is not called.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("What's up")
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
```

Besides the index, it seems that no pages call the function.

The only thing that fixes it is if I turn off app.use(express.static('public')); But then I can't access my page.

What am I supposed to do to get get() working with a /public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of jfriend00's answer it seems I can't do this.
Fortunately, my application doesn't need a get request on the homepage so I set up a views page with the view engine 'pug.' This solved the problem of having "no pages" able to respond to get requests, but if you need to make a get request on a homepage set by express.static() I guess your out of luck?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
var pug = require('pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine','pug');
app.get('/hidden', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("What's up");
  res.render('hidden');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
```

So as long as I have a views/hidden.pug in the root folder I can make a get request to it. This works for me, but perhaps there are other more valid solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If `express.static()` finds a match for the incoming URL, then it handles the request and nothing else gets a chance.  So, you should only be defining routes that don't match filenames in the `public` folder.  Or, you should only be putting files in the `public` folder that you want `express.static()` to match and handle the entire request.

You get one or the other, not both.  Either `express.static()` finds a match and handles the request or it doesn't find a match and your other routes get a chance to match it.